# Serve www.domain to one Heroku app, and *.domain to another

Tags: dns, heroku

I have two apps - One is the public face of the application, and the other is the app itself. I'd like to set up heroku to serve one app (the public site one) to www., and serve up a different app *.domain

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not with Heroku and multiple applications.

If you already have www.domain setup when you try to add the wildcard is suspect it wouldn't let you because the wildcard would also match attempts to www.domain and there's no way to set a priority.

I have apps like you talk of on Heroku and have them all the same codebase and then work out which site should load based off the requested url